# Are there alternatives to ButterflyLabs?

Tags: mining-hardware, asic, butterfly-labs

there's something I want to address... I want to get into mining business, but the problem is that BFLabs has that problem of delays and uncertainty for the shipping date. I want to buy 5 rigs of 500 GHash/s each one, but to have nearly $120k USD stuck for how much time who knows...

Is there any alternative to BFLabs? One that that at least have shipping dates estimates. Many thanks to all.

Comment: There's [KncMiner](https://www.kncminer.com/products/jupiter) but there are similar issues with delivery.

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:Hardware

Answer (score 1):

There are USB ASIC mining equipment on ebay from the company [ASICMinner called Block Errupter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ASICMiner-Block-Erupter-USB-ASIC-Bitcoin-Miner-IN-HAND-not-preorder-/300930082422?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4610d4a676) listed under which is in hand and able to ship imediatly however it is $150 per 333MH/sec which means it would take 2k to reach 5GH/sec. You can order a 5GH/sec BFL for 2.6k and have it shipped today on [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Bitcoin-Mining-Rig-BFL-5-GH-s-Jalapeno-Raspberry-Pi-w-Minepeon-NOT-PRE-ORDER-/141010807068?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20d4e6291c). However with the price of Bitcoins droping it would be wise to consider profitability using [bitcoinx](http://www.bitcoinx.com/profit/) before making a purchase. Also you can contract out your mining http://coinminer.biz/ offer a reasonable rate for a single year.

Answer (score 0):

Find a list of updates on new miners here: http://thegenesisblock.com/category/mining-2/

Comment: Wow! Many thanks for this one! I am very grateful of all the replies! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Kncminers are the most reliable in terms of delivery on time so far, I wouldn't buy butterfly anymore, I sold mine. Block Errupter is too slow 333MH/sec? you will not get back your money with that. If you already have some bitcoin, you can try cexio they do cloud mining for ~0.07 BTC at GH/s that is like 1/4 of the price of the errupter. Butterfly and Kncminers are a lot more cheap (not on ebay though) but there are big question marks on delivery.

Have a look at [cexio](http://goo.gl/1Vy2ur) as you will get a lot of flexibility on trading GH-BTC